# how to post our own iphone Application adds in iAd Controller using iphon sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store-connect, iad, itunes-store

Im My iPhone application i am using iAd controller. In this iAd controller i want to advertise our own mobile apps. How can i do this. Is there anyu settings in itunes connect.

Please help me in this issue

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a simple UIView animation to display your ad in the same fashion. In iTunes Connect I believe you can only exclude ads to be placed in your App.

```
//yourObject setHidden to NO
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
self.yourObject.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
self.yourObject.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can use these animations to mimic a iAd or create your own ad. You can also just have the ad statically on the view, or perhaps use

```
yourObject.alpha = 1;
```

instead of the two lines above commitAnimations.